# Sending POST request from localhost to heroku server?

Tags: node.js, post, reactjs, heroku, axios

Im trying to send a POST request from my React application. The application is running locally in node on localhost:8000.

I've tried running in locally on localhost:5000 and also pushed the server application to a heroku webaddress and tried sending to that address.

**So basically my question is; 
 1. how do I send a POST request to my heroku server when i'm running my react application locally on localhost?
 2. How do I receive this POST request on my heroku server/node application?**

---

React code for sending POST request:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

require('styles/_webshopPage/webshop.css')

export default class Checkout extends Component {

  postRequest() {
        let nodeServerURL = 'https://peaceful-mountain-93404.herokuapp.com'
        let reqData = {
            msg: 'hello!',
        }

        // Send a POST request
        axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: nodeServerURL,
          data: reqData
        })
    }

  render() {
    return (
            <div >
                <button onClick={this.postRequest.bind(this)} type="button" name="button">Send req</button>
            </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Code for my heroku server:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.post('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
})
```

Comment: have your node is running perfect on your heroku?

Comment: I don't understand your question!

Comment: on heroku is your node server running on port 5000?

Comment: I dont really know, where do you see that?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similiar like that..

I think Fetch api works perfectly with it .

Fetch provides a generic definition of Request and Response objects (and other things involved with network requests). This will allow them to be used wherever they are needed in the future, whether it’s for service workers, Cache API and other similar things that handle or modify requests and responses, or any kind of use case that might require you to generate your own responses programmatically.

I have typing some random example here, hope it will you to understand how fetch api exactly works

```
          var data= "somerandom string";
         fetch('http://localhost/react_task/form_send.php', {
                            method: 'post',
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                Password: data,// this is posted on another server
                            })
                        }).then(function (res) {
                            return res.text();
                        }).then((body)=> {
                           console.log(body)// body can be used to get data from another server
                         });
```

i think fetch helps perfectly lot for posting and getting data from another server..

Enjoy Coding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain how this differ from the express library?